# Which software can allow expansion and compression of flowchart components?

Tags: drawing

Is it possible to have expansion and collapsing of flowchart components in any of the flowchart software? Or is there any other feature in any software allowing to have the desired utility of showing the expanded version of a component of flowchart?

OS: Windows 10; 
Price: Both paid or free ones.

[image]